# VS pause program while debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

Is there any way to pause the debugging without breakpoints in VS? (c# Console Application)

I noticed that after a few time my program simply stops working but no exception is thrown, it simply stop doing what it should do.
That's why I wanted to know if there is any way i could pause the code as if there was a breakpoint there, so that i would be able to understand what happend.

The program scrapes data from a website and inserts it into a MS SQL SERVER database if it matters.

**EDIT :**

That's the function that does the magic in my code and scrapes the data from the website. All other things are just data monipulatins.

```
    public static string PostRequest(string url, string request)
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = request;
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

And again no exception is being thrown.
I asked for no breakpoints because the program runs just fine for the first 500 times. Past that number give or take it freezes.

Comment: Could you post part of your code so we can see what it's doing? Also, you could put a try/catch block around your code(if you don't have one already) and put a breakpoint in the catch block. That way you could see what the exception is(if any)

Comment: This sounds a lot like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You can turn on more exception catching when debugging in Visual Studio if you're not seeing it right now. Is your code multi threaded?

Comment: Also, unless you have a VERY thorough logging system, breakpoints is the only way to inspect the state of your program _as_ it's running.

Comment: It's really hard to gauge what you're trying to accomplish here. What do you mean by "stop doing what it should do"? Does it just freeze? Does it crash? However, if your code is stuck, there is a pause button in VS (up top near the other debug controls, such as stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line will break as if it were a break point:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

or

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` somewhere, with some "activation" condition that can trigger it.

As example, you can have a thread just checking for some condition

As a start, something like this (yes, it can be improved, this is just an idea)

```
void CheckAndDebugBreak()
{
    while (true)
    {
        string fileGuard = ...; // whatever file you can easily create/delete
        if (File.Exists(fileGuard))
        {
            File.Delete(fileGuard); // to avoid hitting the breakpoint next time, recreate the file if needed 
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); 
        }
        // some way to stop the infinite loop e.g.
        if (somevariableSetOutside)
            break;

        // wait a while before next check
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only avoiding breakpoints because you don't want to have to manually cycle through, you can try this:

1. Set a break point at the beginning of your function.
2. Mouse over the breakpoint and select the 'gear' symbol
3. Check the "Conditions" box
4. Select "Hit Count" from the first drop down, and set a value

This will stop execution on the breakpoint after that many cycles. So you could run for 500 cycles, then pause at a breakpoint.

Additionally, you can create a Count variable to count the cycles and output the number to the console each cycle to determine exactly how many cycles it makes it through, and if the number is consistent or not.

Answer (score 1):

Select menu **Debug** - **Break All** to break into the next available line of code in an executing app. See [Navigate Code with the Visual Studio Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2017) for more information.

Comment: Very helpful. I initiated remote debugging but all the debugging steps (step into, step out and step over) were greyed out and this is the option which allowed me to pause and control execution